# tf.parse_example.features for Multi-label photo classification

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to apply the tutorial code from cloudml-samples/flowers/ on a set of photos with multi-label. Environment is Google Cloud Shell. "preprocess"ed all training and evaluation set. Running into error when started the training task.

I called the trainer.task through python and returning the below error messages. Please let me know if the log info (only some generic information) through running gcloud beta ml command, or anything else will be helpful.

Thanks in advance for taking the look.

```
python -m trainer.task \
    --output_path gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/training \
    --eval_data_paths gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/preproc/eval* \
    --train_data_paths gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/preproc/train*

INFO:root:Original job data: {}
INFO:root:setting eval batch size to 100
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:968] Invalid argument: Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but output shape: [1]
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError'>, Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but output shape: [1]
         [[Node: inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[2048], [], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch:1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, inputs/ParseExample/Const, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape_1)]]

Caused by op u'inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 559, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 322, in main
    run(model, argv)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 453, in run
    dispatch(args, model, cluster, task)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 494, in dispatch
    Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 193, in run_training
    self.args.batch_size)
  File "trainer/model.py", line 278, in build_train_graph
    return self.build_graph(data_paths, batch_size, GraphMod.TRAIN)
  File "trainer/model.py", line 232, in build_graph
    parsed = tf.parse_example(tensors.examples, features=feature_map)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py", line 307, in parse_example
    dense_types, dense_defaults, dense_shapes, name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py", line 405, in _parse_example_raw
    name=name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py", line 165, in _parse_example
    dense_shapes=dense_shapes, name=name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but output shape: [1]
         [[Node: inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[2048], [], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch:1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, inputs/ParseExample/Const, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape_1)]]

INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError'>, Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but output shape: [1]
         [[Node: inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[2048], [], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch:1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, inputs/ParseExample/Const, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape_1)]]

Caused by op u'inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 559, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 322, in main
    run(model, argv)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 453, in run
    dispatch(args, model, cluster, task)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 494, in dispatch
    Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 193, in run_training
    self.args.batch_size)
  File "trainer/model.py", line 278, in build_train_graph
    return self.build_graph(data_paths, batch_size, GraphMod.TRAIN)
  File "trainer/model.py", line 232, in build_graph
    parsed = tf.parse_example(tensors.examples, features=feature_map)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py", line 307, in parse_example
    dense_types, dense_defaults, dense_shapes, name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py", line 405, in _parse_example_raw
    name=name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py", line 165, in _parse_example
    dense_shapes=dense_shapes, name=name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but output shape: [1]
         [[Node: inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[2048], [], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch:1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, inputs/ParseExample/Const, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape_1)]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 559, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 322, in main
    run(model, argv)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 453, in run
    dispatch(args, model, cluster, task)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 494, in dispatch
    Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 245, in run_training
    self.global_step = session.run(to_run)[0]
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but output shape: [1]
         [[Node: inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[2048], [], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch:1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, inputs/ParseExample/Const, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape_1)]]

Caused by op u'inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 559, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 322, in main
    run(model, argv)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 453, in run
    dispatch(args, model, cluster, task)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 494, in dispatch
    Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training()
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/git/cloudml-samples/yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/trainer/task.py", line 193, in run_training
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError'>, Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index:
    self.args.batch_size)
  File "trainer/model.py", line 278, in build_train_graph
    return self.build_graph(data_paths, batch_size, GraphMod.TRAIN)
  File "trainer/model.py", line 232, in build_graph
    parsed = tf.parse_example(tensors.examples, features=feature_map)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py", line 307, in parse_example
    dense_types, dense_defaults, dense_shapes, name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py", line 405, in _parse_example_raw
    name=name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py", line 165, in _parse_example
    dense_shapes=dense_shapes, name=name)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/slalomconsultingsf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Name: <unknown>, Key: label, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 5 but outpu
t shape: [1]
         [[Node: inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_shapes=[[2048], [
], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch:1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/names, inputs/ParseExamp
le/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, inputs/ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, inputs/ParseExample/Const
, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape, inputs/ParseExample/Reshape_1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The flowers sample does not directly support multi-label classification.  The exact problem in your code I believe is related to the [shape=[1] in model.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/trainer/model.py#L226).

Alas plugging in multi-label examples will not work out of the box with this code, which was designed to be a good example of how to get started with a complex workflow (ie restoring from checkpoints, transfer learning, embedding in Dataflow, etc), more so than an image modeling Swiss army knife.

There should be only a few lines you would have to make changes to model.py to get your multi-label example working though.  Furthermore, I'm sure other members of the community would greatly appreciate any progress you make so please consider creating a [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/pulls), should you get a sample that does both multi and single-label problems!